# How to use a parameter of type `Derived` in a overridden method accepting `Base`?

Tags: java, generics, interface, overriding

I have the following situation:

```
abstract class Base {
    int data = 0;
    void baseMethod() {
        System.out.println("baseMethod:" + data);
    }
}

class DerivedA extends Base {
    void DerivedBMethodA() {

    }

    void usefulMethod(Something something) {
        something.doSomething(this);
    }

    interface Something {
        void doSomething(DerivedA deriv);
    }
}

class DerivedB extends Base {
    void DerivedMethodB() {

    }
}

public class Temp {

    public static void main() {
        DerivedA a = new DerivedA();
        a.usefulMethod(new DerivedA.Something() {
            @Override
            public void doSomething(DerivedA deriv) {
                deriv.DerivedBMethodA();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

I want to push `usefulMethod` and `Something` upto the `Base` class so that `DerivedB` can leverage it. And I want implementations of `Something.doSomething` to be able to use a derived type, so that it can access derived functionality.

How do I do that?

#### Attempts

I've tried the following:

```
abstract class Base {
    int data = 0;
    void baseMethod() {
        System.out.println("baseMethod:" + data);
    }


    void usefulMethod(Something something) {
        something.doSomething(this);
    }

    interface Something {
        void doSomething(Base deriv);
    }
}

class DerivedA extends Base {
    void DerivedBMethodA() {

    }
}

class DerivedB extends Base {
    void DerivedMethodB() {

    }
}

public class Temp {

    public static void main() {
        DerivedA a = new DerivedA();
        a.usefulMethod(new Base.Something() {
            @Override
            public void doSomething(DerivedA deriv) {
                deriv.DerivedBMethodA();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

but that fails as my anonymous `Something` doesn't implement `doSomething(Base)`. So trying to use generics:

I tried:

```
    interface Something {
        void doSomething(<? extends Base> deriv);
    }
```

but that won't compile due to: "Wildcards may be used only as reference parameters"

I tried:

```
    interface Something {
        <T extends Base> void doSomething(T deriv);
    }
```

but that requires me to implement the interface as so:

```
        a.usefulMethod(new Base.Something() {
            @Override
            public <T extends Base> void doSomething(T deriv) {

            }
        });
```

which obviously doesn't allow me access to the derived type?

There are ways I can make it "work" but they're undesirable:

1. This:

   ```
   interface Something {
       void doSomething(Base deriv);
   }

       a.usefulMethod(new Base.Something() {
           @Override
           public void doSomething(Base deriv) {
               DerivedA a1 = (DerivedA) deriv;
               a1.DerivedBMethodA();
           }
       });
   ```

   But that requires me to cast in each implementation, which seems wasteful.
2. And this:

   ```
   package com.miurasample.ui.info;


   abstract class Base {
       int data = 0;
       void baseMethod() {
           System.out.println("baseMethod:" + data);
       }


       void usefulMethod(Something something) {
           something.doSomething(this);
       }

       interface Something<T extends Base> {
           void doSomething(T deriv);
       }
   }

   public class Temp {

       public static void main() {
           DerivedA a = new DerivedA();
           a.usefulMethod(new Base.Something<DerivedA>() {
               @Override
               public void doSomething(DerivedA deriv) {

               }
           });
       }
   }
   ```

but that results in a warning/IDE highlight in `usefulMethod` of:

"Unchecked call to doSomething(T) as a member of raw type `Base.Something`"

**What's the tersest and "cleanest" way to do this**? Is that I'm doing even sane?

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to say if your design is wrong or not. We dont have full scope of your requirements to assert that, but here is clean non cast approach to what you are trying to do. It does require extra method in your derived classes:

```
public static void main(String... args) {
        DerivedA a = new DerivedA();

        a.usefulMethod( new Base.Something<DerivedA>() {
            @Override
            public void doSomething(DerivedA deriv) {
                deriv.DerivedBMethodA();
            }
        } );
    }

    public abstract static class Base< T extends Base<T> > {
        int data = 0;

        protected abstract T getThis();

        void baseMethod() {
            System.out.println("baseMethod:" + data);
        }

        void usefulMethod(Something<T> something) {
            something.doSomething( getThis() );
        }

        interface Something< T extends Base<T> > {
            void doSomething(T deriv);
        }
    }

    public static class DerivedA extends Base<DerivedA> {

        protected DerivedA getThis(){
            return this;
        }

        void DerivedBMethodA() {}
    }

    public static class DerivedB extends Base<DerivedB> {

        protected DerivedB getThis(){
            return this;
        }

        void DerivedMethodB() {}
    }
```